# Radio value is only change when close and reopen the showModalBottomSheet in Flutter

Tags: flutter

This radio button inside showModalBottomSheet is only change when I close and reopen this modalBottomSheet. setState is not working properly there. Can anyone solve this and say why this is happening?

But when I put these radio out from the modal sheet it works normally.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [showModalBottomSheet].

void main() => runApp(const BottomSheetApp());

class BottomSheetApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomSheetApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Sample')),
        body: const BottomSheetExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomSheetExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomSheetExample({super.key});
    @override
  State<BottomSheetExample> createState() => _BottomSheetExampleState();
}

class _BottomSheetExampleState extends State<BottomSheetExample> {
  int _selectedOption = 0;
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    void handleRadioValueChanged(int? value) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedOption = value!;
      });
    }
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                     ListTile(
                      title: const Text("Administrative Associate"),
                      trailing: Radio(
                          value: 2,
                          groupValue: _selectedOption,
                          onChanged: handleRadioValueChanged),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text("Account Manager"),
                      trailing: Radio(
                          value: 3,
                          groupValue: _selectedOption,
                          onChanged: handleRadioValueChanged),
                    ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to get the changed value without closing  it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [showModalBottomSheet].

void main() => runApp(const BottomSheetApp());

class BottomSheetApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const BottomSheetApp({super.key});

 @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         home: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Sample')),
         body: const BottomSheetExample(),
         ),
       );
      }
    }

    class BottomSheetExample extends StatefulWidget {
    const BottomSheetExample({super.key});
    @override
   State<BottomSheetExample> createState() => _BottomSheetExampleState();
   }

  class _BottomSheetExampleState extends State<BottomSheetExample> {
  int _selectedOption = 0;


  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   void handleRadioValueChanged(int? value,StateSetter setState) {
     setState(() {
     _selectedOption = value!;
    });
   }
     return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
       child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder:(BuildContext context,StateSetter setState) =>  SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                   ListTile(
                    title: const Text("Administrative Associate"),
                    trailing: Radio(
                        value: 2,
                        groupValue: _selectedOption,
                        onChanged: (value) => handleRadioValueChanged(value,setState)),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text("Account Manager"),
                    trailing: Radio(
                        value: 3,
                        groupValue: _selectedOption,
                        onChanged: (value) => handleRadioValueChanged(value,setState)),
                  ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can I make this showModalBottomSheet into a widget? if possible then how can I pass the stateSetter then?

Answer (score 1):

Add your widget inside [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html)

```
ElevatedButton(
    child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
    onPressed: () {
      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter stateSetter) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        title: const Text("Administrative Associate"),
                        trailing: Radio(
                            value: 2,
                            groupValue: _selectedOption,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              stateSetter(() {
                                handleRadioValueChanged(value);
                              });
                            }),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: const Text("Account Manager"),
                        trailing: Radio(
                            value: 3,
                            groupValue: _selectedOption,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              stateSetter(() {
                                handleRadioValueChanged(value);
                              });
                            }),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

#### Updated Answer

Your widget:

```
ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return CustomModelSheet(selectedOption: _selectedOption);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

Bottomsheet widget:

```
class CustomModelSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomModelSheet({
    super.key,
    required int selectedOption,
  }) : selectedOption = selectedOption;

  int selectedOption;

  @override
  State<CustomModelSheet> createState() => _CustomModelSheetState();
}

class _CustomModelSheetState extends State<CustomModelSheet> {
  void handleRadioValueChanged(int? value) {
    setState(() {
      widget.selectedOption = value!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter stateSetter) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text("Administrative Associate"),
                  trailing: Radio(
                      value: 2,
                      groupValue: widget.selectedOption,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        stateSetter(() {
                          handleRadioValueChanged(value);
                        });
                      }),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text("Account Manager"),
                  trailing: Radio(
                      value: 3,
                      groupValue: widget.selectedOption,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        stateSetter(() {
                          handleRadioValueChanged(value);
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can I make this showModalBottomSheet into a widget? if possible then how can I pass the stateSetter then?